# Does this question need a for or while loop or?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

> A University is testing a new fertilizer. They are interested in how long the fertilizer may be kept before its effectiveness is lost. They have done some calculations that indicate the fertilizer loses 6% of its potency every month. Design a Python algorithm that finds how many months it takes before the fertilizer has lost more than 50% of its effective power after which is must be thrown away. The first four months of potency figures would look like this:
>
> ```
> Month 1, potency 100%
> Month 2, potency 94%
> Month 3, potency 88.36%
> Month 4, potency 83.0584%
> ...
> Loses potency at month xx
> ```

I don't necessarily want the answer, just a starting point.

Comment: `log(.5) / log(1 - .06) = ~11.2 months` no loop required.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I somehow doubt that's the intended solution. :-) Guessing the class wants you to learn to write loops, and while your answer is the better solution in the real world, it's also not teaching them the important concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Either works. For a class for "complete beginners", they'd almost certainly expect you to use a `while`, because there's no fixed number of iterations to solve the problem, so a `while` testing your stop condition is the straightforward solution; you'd just have to manually track how many months had passed along with computing the new efficacy rating each month.

With the simple tools available to beginners (no or minimal module imports), infinite `for` loops aren't really a thing, but more advanced Python techniques would let you write an infinite `for` loop that would track the month for you, e.g.:

```
 for month in itertools.count(1):  # Requires import itertools at top of file
     # Perform your iterative recalculation of efficacy
     # When it reaches 50%, break out of the loop and month will already have the correct value
```

but the distinction between the two solutions isn't enough to strongly favor one or the other (the `for` would be microscopically faster, at the expense of requiring an `import`, thanks to pushing some of the basic math to the C layer on the CPython reference interpreter).

Comment: Yeah I believe they definitely want us to use one of those loops. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop or a while loop. Both works. Albeit I would probably use a while loop here as we aren't sure for how many iterations we need to go through.

The potency at month `n` is given by `0.94**n`

Comment: No need to even use exponentiation; if you're running the loop anyway, you can just repeatedly multiply your work-to-date by `0.94`. Admittedly, recomputing `0.94 ** n` would (probably) slightly improve precision (floating point tends to accumulate errors from repeated single operations; recomputing from scratch as a bulk operation often reduces the accumulated errors).

Comment: That's helpful from you both thank you as I didn't even think about multiplying by 0.94.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree. It was just to illustrate to the OP how it is calculated in theory to give them an idea of how you could possibly calculate it. I think the best thing a beginner can do is try to map it out on a piece of paper with a pen and then follow their written algorithm.

Comment: How would I improve this code for the above problem?                potency = 100
month = 1
while potency >= 50:
    potency *= 0.94
    month +=1
    print(potency)
    print('This is month',month)

Comment: @scientist: Can't show proper code formatting in a comment, but assuming the right things are in the `while` loop, that's the straightforward solution (where the reported month number is the potency at the *beginning* of that month, not *after* that many months, since as written month 1 still has 100% potency). Nothing to improve.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you. Yes I think mine reports the potency for that month as the beginning of the month. With practice I'll get there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).